# How to know the last database before a procedure (in another database) was called

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, exec

The caller of the procedure who is in database AAA:-

```
use AAA
exec BBB.dbo.ap_MyProc
```

The procedure being called which is in database BBB:-

```
use BBB
create procedure ap_MyProc as
print 'We want a way to return the database name AAA'
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That's product specific functionality.)

Comment: SQL Server.  It would be nice if the answer is compatible with 2008 but I'll take 2012 answers too.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can your stored procedure be edited? If yes, I think you can edit the stored procedures and add one more parameter for the database name.

And during calling the stored procedure, you should pass the `db_name()` into the new parameter, so that your stored procedure could know which database is calling it

```
DECLARE @ServerName varchar(50) = db_name()

EXEC [dbo].[SP] @newParams = @ServerName
```

Comment: This is not a feasible workaround in our scenario because the procedures being called in database BBB are being executed from shortcutkeys.

Comment: what is the meaning of a shortcutkey?

Comment: You can specify Query Shortcuts and assign them to the keyboard in SQL Server Management Studio (Tools, Options, Keyboard, Query Shortcuts).  So for example I have mu own 'sp_helptext2' on there.  The imposed limitations of shortcut keys is a whole subject by itself and not one to go into here.

Answer (score 0):

Well i can now answer my own question.  We can exploit syslockinfo...

```
declare @db_name varchar(255)

select
    @db_name = db_name(rsc_dbid)
from
    master.dbo.syslockinfo
where
    req_spid = @@SPID 
    and req_ownertype = 4 --"exSession"
    and rsc_dbid <> db_id()

select @db_name = isnull(@db_name, db_name())

print @db_name
```

Works in SQL 2008 as well. :)